# Stop click event propagation in ionic frameworks $ionicActionSheet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using `$ionicActionSheet` and underneath it (before it's opened) there is textarea.  When the user clicks the button in the `$ionicActionSheet` it also brings focus to the `<textarea>` below and opens the keyboard.  Is there any way to stop the click propagation in the `$ionicActionSheet`?

```
    $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Camera'
        }, {
            text: 'Photo Library'
        }],
        destructiveText: 'Cancel',
        destructiveButtonClicked: function() {


            //
            // How do I get access to the click event?
            $event.stopPropagation();
            //
            //


            return true;
        },
        buttonClicked: function(index) {


            //
            // How do I get access to the click event?
            $event.stopPropagation();
            //
            //


            if(index == 0) {
                $scope.TakePicture("camera");
            } else {
                $scope.TakePicture("library");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So is it like that the action sheet is open and the textarea gains the focus, and the keyboard pops up ??

Comment: After the actionsheet closes from clicking a button, if the button was over the textarea it gives focus to the textarea and opens the keyboard.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @ZWand19 No, it might just not be possible.  I ended up adding a bit of a hack, I just force the keyboard to close even if it's not open.

Comment: Recognizing this is an old thread, but I am seeing this behavior with buttons behind the ActionSheet.